# Color numbers in a matrix based on their values

Tags: r, colors, numbers

I have a 2 by 2 matrix and I would like to color the numbers based on their values (say I have numbers from 0-20 and I want to color 0-2=blue; 2-4=sky blue... 12-14=yellow, 18-20=red, etc.). In Excel I was only able to have 3 colors with the Conditional Formatting option (see the figure). Anyone knows if I can have more colors in another program (preferably R). Thanks!

PS: Please note, I do not need a heatmap or contour plot per se, because I am interested in the exact values of the numbers.

[image: snapshot of my excel spreadsheet with the 3 colors based on the values of the numbers]

Comment: xlsx package might be useful. it seems like you can set color ar font parameters of individual cells using that

Comment: Excel 2008 for Mac, version 12.3.6

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, I hope it helps

```
# you need this for the colour ramp
library(RColorBrewer)

# setup
rows <- 10
collumns <- 10

# data matrix
zVals <- round(rnorm(rows*collumns), 2)
z <- matrix(zVals, rows, collumns)

# pick the number of colours (granularity of colour scale)
nColors <- 100

# create the colour pallete
cols <-colorRampPalette(colors=c("blue", "grey", "red"))(nColors)

# get a zScale for the colours
zScale <- seq(min(z), max(z), length.out = nColors)

# function that returns the nearest colour given a value of z
findNearestColour <- function(x) {
        colorIndex <- which(abs(zScale - x) == min(abs(zScale - x)))
        return(cols[colorIndex])
}

# empty plot
plot(1, 1, type = "n", xlim = c(1, rows), ylim = c(1, collumns), 
     axes = F, xlab = "", ylab = "")

# populate it with the data
for(r in 1:rows){
    for(c in 1:collumns){
        text(c, r, z[c,r], col = findNearestColour(z[c,r])) 
    }
}
```

[image: Numbers coloured by value]

Comment: oops sorry you wanted colour bins of certain ranges? one way you could do this is by modifying (and maybe renaming) the `findNearestColour()` function above. i hope it gives you a starting point anyway, feel free to message me for explanations.

Comment: if you want equal sized colour bins (but fewer) you can reduce `nColors` the granularity of the scale.

Comment: Please post a screen shot of this.